# Auto carousel in css/js/jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, carousel

I need your help to create a carousel that would automatically and continuously turn. The goal is that it never stops, rotates in a fluid way and when you put the mouse on one of the elements it stops rotating.
I have already made a part of code, which turns automatically but simulates a click on one of the arrows and as you can see it gives an animation: slow down - speed up - slow down while I am looking for something continuous.

My code :

```js
var carousel = $(".carousel"),
    items = $(".item"),
    currdeg  = 0;

$(".next").on("click", { d: "n" }, rotate);
$(".prev").on("click", { d: "p" }, rotate);

function rotate(e){
  if(e.data.d=="n"){
    currdeg = currdeg - 60;
  }
  if(e.data.d=="p"){
    currdeg = currdeg + 60;
  }
  carousel.css({
    "-webkit-transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)",
    "-moz-transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)",
    "-o-transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)",
    "transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)"
  });
    items.css({
    "-webkit-transform": "rotateY("+(-currdeg)+"deg)",
    "-moz-transform": "rotateY("+(-currdeg)+"deg)",
    "-o-transform": "rotateY("+(-currdeg)+"deg)",
    "transform": "rotateY("+(-currdeg)+"deg)"
  });
}

/*var btn = document.querySelector(".next");
console.log(btn);
setInterval(function(){
btn.click();
},700);*/
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  padding: 70px 0;
  font: 15px/20px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 120px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.carousel {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
}
.carousel div {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  
}

.item {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0.95;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-animation: rotating 1s linear infinite;
}

.a {
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(250px);
}
.b {
  transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(250px) rotateY(-60deg);
}
.c {
  transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(250px)  rotateY(-120deg);
}
.d {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(250px) rotateY(-180deg);
}
.e {
  transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(250px) rotateY(-240deg);
} 
.f {
  transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(250px) rotateY(-300deg);
}

.next, .prev {
  color: #444;
  position: absolute;
  top: 240px;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.next:hover, .prev:hover { color: #000; }
.next:active, .prev:active {
  top: 240px;
}
.next { right: 5em; }
.prev { left: 5em; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="carousel" id="carousel2">
      <div class="a">
        <div class="item"><a href="https://chateaupouzols.com/chardonnay/"><img src="https://chateaupouzols.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/v1-2.png"/></a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="b">
        <div class="item"><a href="https://chateaupouzols.com/1437-2/"><img src="https://chateaupouzols.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/v2-2-2.png"/></a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="c">
        <div class="item"><a href="https://chateaupouzols.com/cabernet-sauvignon/"><img src="https://chateaupouzols.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/v3-2.png"/></a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="d">
        <div class="item"><a href="https://chateaupouzols.com/merlot/"><img src="https://chateaupouzols.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/v4-2.png"/></a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="e">
        <div class="item"><a href="https://chateaupouzols.com/la-gardye/"><img src="https://chateaupouzols.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/v5-2.png"/></a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="f">
        <div class="item"><a href="https://chateaupouzols.com/syrah/"><img src="https://chateaupouzols.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/v6-2.png"/></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="next"><img style="width:30px;" src="https://chateaupouzols.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/fleshD-3.png"/></div>
  <div class="prev"><img style="width:30px;" src="https://chateaupouzols.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/fleshG-3.png"/></div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance for your response and have a nice day !

Comment: is there anything specifically wrong with the code? if so please could you indicate what and explain what you have tried so far?

Comment: Not specifically wrong, i just want to update the code to do a automatic loop on the carousel.

Comment: There are at least a thousand carousel jQuery plugins out there already. Does none of them fit your needs? Why do you need to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @JeremyThille I reinveted it because i didn't found the type of carousel that i need to do. On internet i just found carousel types like a pic going on left and disappear, here i need that the bottle turn as if they were on a plate.

Comment: You mean that none of the 1000 jQuery carousel plugins out there has ever thought of implementing infinite looping? On the contrary, I'm pretty sure most, if not all of them do. I googled "jQuery carousel", first result was [slick](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), and directly on the home page, the first demo/example is an infinitely looping carousel that goes back to 1 after 6... Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Of course i'm based on a existing carousel i sYes it's what i need to do but in a more fluid way. I need that the carousel never stop in the sense of a spinner, all the auto carousel i saw on google was with a stop time on each image, i need to have a constant tourning status. 
I you don't see what i want or a little to confused i can try to explain more in detail ! :/

Comment: PS... there's no need to `-vendor-` prefix in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Add click trigger using jQuery.

setInterval 5000 will trigger the click every 5 seconds.

```js
setInterval(function(){
    $(".next").trigger('click')
}, 5000)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Kapil Sharma !  its the part i have done one time (it was on comment in the code sorry). Do you know how to do this without the animation of the rotate() of js? (the animation of slowed down then accelerated then slowed down another time) I need a fluid animation if you see what i say :)

Comment: @JulienCanet Ah, I see what you are trying to achieve. I will give it a try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I'd achieve that by using the hover method of jQuery. This method can accept one to two arguments, the first one is called the `handlerIn` which can be translated as the hover state, mouse enter, etc and the `handlerOut` which corressponds to the 'mouse leave' event.

On window `onLoad()` you can use `setInterval()` that returns an interval, which you can pass to clear the interval on mouse hover.

```
window.onload = function()
{
  refresh = setInterval(function (){
      $(".next").trigger('click')
  }, 1000);
};

$('#carousel2').hover(mouseEnter, mouseLeave);
function mouseEnter() {
     clearInterval(refresh);
};
function mouseLeave() {
       refresh = setInterval(function (){
      $(".next").trigger('click')
  }, 1000);
};
```

```js
var carousel = $(".carousel"),
    items = $(".item"),
    currdeg  = 0;

$(".next").on("click", { d: "n" }, rotate);
$(".prev").on("click", { d: "p" }, rotate);

function rotate(e){
  if(e.data.d=="n"){
    currdeg = currdeg - 60;
  }
  if(e.data.d=="p"){
    currdeg = currdeg + 60;
  }
  carousel.css({
    "-webkit-transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)",
    "-moz-transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)",
    "-o-transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)",
    "transform": "rotateY("+currdeg+"deg)"
  });
    items.css({
    "-webkit-transform": "rotateY("+(-currdeg)+"deg)",
    "-moz-transform": "rotateY("+(-currdeg)+"deg)",
    "-o-transform": "rotateY("+(-currdeg)+"deg)",
    "transform": "rotateY("+(-currdeg)+"deg)"
  });
}

/*var btn = document.querySelector(".next");
console.log(btn);
setInterval(function(){
btn.click();
},700);*/

window.onload = function()
{
  refresh = setInterval(function (){
      $(".next").trigger('click')
  }, 1000);
};

$('#carousel2').hover(mouseEnter, mouseLeave);
function mouseEnter() {
     clearInterval(refresh);
};
function mouseLeave() {
       refresh = setInterval(function (){
      $(".next").trigger('click')
  }, 1000);
};
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  padding: 70px 0;
  font: 15px/20px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 120px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.carousel {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
}
.carousel div {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  
}

.item {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0.95;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-animation: rotating 1s linear infinite;
}

.a {
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(250px);
}
.b {
  transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(250px) rotateY(-60deg);
}
.c {
  transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(250px)  rotateY(-120deg);
}
.d {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(250px) rotateY(-180deg);
}
.e {
  transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(250px) rotateY(-240deg);
} 
.f {
  transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(250px) rotateY(-300deg);
}

.next, .prev {
  color: #444;
  position: absolute;
  top: 240px;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.next:hover, .prev:hover { color: #000; }
.next:active, .prev:active {
  top: 240px;
}
.next { right: 5em; }
.prev { left: 5em; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="carousel" id="carousel2">
      <div class="a">
        <div class="item"><a href="https://chateaupouzols.com/chardonnay/"><img src="https://chateaupouzols.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/v1-2.png"/></a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="b">
        <div class="item"><a href="https://chateaupouzols.com/1437-2/"><img src="https://chateaupouzols.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/v2-2-2.png"/></a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="c">
        <div class="item"><a href="https://chateaupouzols.com/cabernet-sauvignon/"><img src="https://chateaupouzols.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/v3-2.png"/></a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="d">
        <div class="item"><a href="https://chateaupouzols.com/merlot/"><img src="https://chateaupouzols.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/v4-2.png"/></a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="e">
        <div class="item"><a href="https://chateaupouzols.com/la-gardye/"><img src="https://chateaupouzols.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/v5-2.png"/></a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="f">
        <div class="item"><a href="https://chateaupouzols.com/syrah/"><img src="https://chateaupouzols.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/v6-2.png"/></a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="next"><img style="width:30px;" src="https://chateaupouzols.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/fleshD-3.png"/></div>
  <div class="prev"><img style="width:30px;" src="https://chateaupouzols.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/fleshG-3.png"/></div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```